# pinterest type scrolling

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone know how [pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) is doing its scrolling. Is there any jquery components or something like that that can handle this kind of lazy loading setup.

Thanks

Comment: [They use jQuery Masonry to handle the layout](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and [jQuery's Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Comment: But talking about the "scrolling"... really you need a jquery plugin to do it?? What about taking the current position of the cursor and the height of the screen?

Comment: Can jQuery's Infinite Scroll load json data to render on the page. From what I'm seeing its using static html links to render on the page? I can't seem to find a good tutorial on how to setup this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just needs a little creativity:

Step 1: Place an element at the base of your content stack.

Step 2: Write a function that detects when that element in at or near the bottom of the view port.

Step 3: Write a function that loads more content

Step 4: Use the function from step 2 to fire the function from step 3.

Comment: So how would you handle the page load if you are lest say 4 or 5 lots of content loaded on the page and you refresh the page. How would you loaded the content based on a refresh.

Comment: Again, bit of creativity. Store some data in a cookie or URL hash relating the the volume of content to load.